# Why is RewriteCond needed for this rule to work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I have the re-write rule:

```
RewriteRule ([^?]*) /script.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It will return a 500 internal error unless I also have the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Why is this? I was under the impression that the conditions didn't actually change how the rule works but rather they were just exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Look in your apache error log to see what the actual error is, but it is very likely a redirect loop that proceeds infinitely. The condition is needed to make sure that the redirect only occurs if it isn't a real file (so script.php doesn't redirect infinitely to itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` tests if the given argument is a file and if it exists (it could be 0 bytes in size). The reason why you get a 500 internal server error is because the rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing. So for example, if all you had was this:

```
RewriteRule ([^?]*) /script.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And a request comes in as `/foobar` the URI is "foobar"

1. "foobar" matches `([^?]*)`, URI gets rewritten as "/script.php?path=foobar"
2. rewrite engine loops
3. "script.php" matches `([^?]*)`, URI gets rewritten as "/script.php?path=script"
4. rewrite engine loops
5. etc.

Now if you add the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^?]*) /script.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And the request comes in as `/foobar` the URI is "foobar"

1. "foobar" is not a file that exists, `!-f` is true
2. "foobar" matches `([^?]*)`, URI gets rewritten as "/script.php?path=foobar"
3. rewrite engine loops
4. "script.php" **is** a file that exists, `!-f` is false
5. condition is false so rule isn't applied. Rewriting stops, the resulting URI is "/script.php?path=foobar"

Comment: Thank you for stepping through the process. I didn't realise it looped. So if I just wanted to exclude that single script file I'd just have a condition that tests %{REQUEST_URI} for that script?

Answer (score 1):

This is your rule:

```
RewriteRule ([^?]*) /script.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here `([^?]*)` matches 0 or more length of anything but `?`. And then it rewrites it to `/script.php` URI. Resulting URI is injected again for evaluation. Please note that `([^?]*)` will match again since it 0 or more of `non-?` and rule gets applied again. This looping goes on until mod_rewrite runs out of recursion limit (default=10).

Now when you have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^?]*) /script.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means apply next `RewriteRule` if request is not for a valid file.

Now after first rewrite the target URI `/script.php` is a valid file and `RewriteCond` fails this time and rule isn't applied again.

**PS:** This matching pattern `([^?]*)` will ALWAYS match all URI patterns since REQUEST_URI can never contain a `?`

**You rule is equivalent of:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /script.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: My intention was to match all uri patterns but I didn't realise there was a short hand for this. Thanks.